# Согласование с числительным на «4»

Tags: согласование, числительные

«Подготовлено 1274 соглашения....» Верно ли это? Или если одна тысяча, то должно быть «подготовленА». Или по среднему роду «соглашение»....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это верно: «***Подготовлено 1274 соглашения***....»

А вот задаваемые вопросы говорят о **непонимании следующих тем**, связанных с числительными.

**1. О согласовании счетного  оборота со сказуемым**

1.1. Счетный оборот рассматривается как **единый член предложения** при согласовании со сказуемым.

1.2. Сказуемое может иметь формы **как единственного,  так и множественного числа**, причем в единственном числе счетному обороту приписывается значение **среднего рода.**  Но средний род существительного ***соглашение*** никакого влияния не оказывает, можно сказать: *подготовлено 1274 **ответа***).

Сказуемое имеет форму **ед. числа** в том случае, если существительное в составе подлежащего обозначает **неодушевленные** предметы, а также если в предложении подчеркивается **пассивность** действующих лиц.

1.3. Поэтому правильно: подготовлено 1274 соглашения (ср.род. ед. число).

**2.  О выборе падежа  существительного**

2.1. **Особенности** выбора падежа существительного **для составных числительных**

1274 – это составное числительное, в этом случае  выбора падежа для существительных делается **по конечному числительному** 4, сравнить: ***подготовлено 4 соглашения –  подготовлено 1274 соглашения.***

Соответственно, слово ***тысяча*** никаким образом не влияет ни на выбор падежа существительного, ни на согласование со сказуемым.

**2.2. Выбор падежа для существительного в счетном обороте (общее правило)**

Счетный оборот в общем случае **изменяется по падежам**: четыре соглашения – о четырех соглашениях, к четырем соглашениям.

При этом в И.п. и В.п. числительное задает **Р.п. существительному** (грамматическая связь управление), а в косвенных падежах согласуется с существительным (грамматическая связь согласование).

**2.3. Особенности выбора числа существительного для числительных два, три, четыре**

Сравним: *два, три, четыре **соглашения** – пять **соглашений**.*

В сочетаниях с числительными **2, 3, 4**  существительное используется в форме **ед. числа** (а не мн. числа, как для других числительных).

**3. Вывод**

Как вы видите, тема числительных требует  **четкого знания базовой информации**, которую нужно хорошо усвоить.

Только в этом случае **имеет смысл  заниматься этой темой**.